# Python `beanie` mongo ODM: Bulk update with upsert=True

Tags: python, mongodb, python-asyncio, tornado-motor, beanie

I am using `beanie==1.10.1`

I want to perform bulk operation with updating multiple documents with `upsert=True`. I expect following code to insert full document if find query didn't give results.
I was using this as a reference: https://github.com/roman-right/beanie/blob/main/tests/odm/documents/test_bulk_write.py

Here is full code:

```
import beanie
import asyncio
import random
from beanie import BulkWriter
from beanie.odm.operators.update.general import Set
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient


class TestDoc(beanie.Document):
    a: str
    b: int


async def init_mongo():
    mongo_client = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")
    await beanie.init_beanie(
        database=mongo_client.db_name, document_models=[TestDoc]
    )


async def run_test():
    await init_mongo()

    docs = [TestDoc(a=f"id_{i}", b=random.randint(1, 100)) for i in range(10)]
    async with BulkWriter() as bulk_writer:
        for doc in docs:
            await TestDoc \
                .find_one({TestDoc.a: doc.a}, bulk_writer=bulk_writer) \
                .upsert(Set({TestDoc.b: doc.b}), on_insert=doc, bulk_writer=bulk_writer)
                # .update_one(Set(doc), bulk_writer=bulk_writer, upsert=True)

    read_docs = await TestDoc.find().to_list()
    print(f"read_docs: {read_docs}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    pool.run_until_complete(run_test())
```

After executing no documents are inserted into db. Not with `.upsert()` nor with `.update_one()` method. What is correct way to achieve that logic?

With `pymongo` such operation would be written like so (and it works):

```
def write_reviews(self, docs: List[TestDoc]):
    operations = []
    for doc in docs:
        doc_dict = to_dict(doc)
        update_operation = pymongo.UpdateOne(
            {"a": doc.a}, {"$set": doc_dict}, upsert=True
        )
        operations.append(update_operation)

    result = self.test_collection.bulk_write(operations)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old, and you probably figured it out but since its the first result in a google search for me I thought I would answer.

The current way you use bulk_writer is just wrapping the options and then committing them.

```
from beanie.odm.operators.update.general import Set

async def run_test():
    await init_mongo()

    docs = [TestDoc(a=f"id_{i}", b=random.randint(1, 100)) for i in range(10)]
    async with BulkWriter() as bulk_writer:
        for doc in docs:
            await TestDoc \
                .find_one({TestDoc.a: doc.a}) \
                .upsert(Set({TestDoc.b: doc.b}), on_insert=doc)
        bulk_writer.commit()        

    read_docs = await TestDoc.find().to_list()
    print(f"read_docs: {read_docs}")
```

[Original Test in Beanie Test Suite](https://github.com/roman-right/beanie/blob/main/tests/odm/documents/test_bulk_write.py#L128)

Comment: In this case, where is Set imported from?

Comment: from beanie.odm.operators.update.general import Set